# libpng15.so.15, cannot open shared object file

Tags: compiling, shared-library, blender

I recently downloaded a binary of Blender, and upon running it on got the following error:

```
jdphenix@jdphenix:~/blender/blender_59865$ ./blender
./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My first thought was to search for libpng using `apt-cache`, but no versions matched what Blender was looking for, so I downloaded the libpng v15 source from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/ and built it using the normal `./configure`, `make install` type routine.

After this, I still got the same error, so I checked `whereis`:

```
jdphenix@jdphenix:~/blender/blender_59865$ whereis libpng15.so.15
libpng15.so: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.so /usr/local/lib/libpng15.so.15
```

It where I expected it to be. Checked http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout and saw `blender --help`. No dice, because it requires `libpng15.so.15` to even do that.

At this point, I feel that I might be missing something fundamental here. Is there something else I can break/unbreak/try to get this up and running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, it seems that Blender seeks this library inside `/usr/lib` instead of `/usr/local/lib`. The answer is trivial: make there *symbolic link*:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng15.so /usr/lib
```

Else, you can change prefix while `./configure` your libpng.so:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Thus `make install` will install libpng15.so direct into `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Something else ended up panning out quite nicely - I just installed the blender package from the official ppa (`sudo apt-get install blender`), it took care of the dependencies in one install step. I'm even able to compile without much work after that :)